# Venezuelan traveling from US to Venezuela with Expired Passport. How to?

Tags: passport-renewals, venezuelan-citizens

I'm currently in the US (legally) and want to travel to Caracas. My passport recently expired. Unfortunately , there is no Venezuelan consulates in the US, and there are no direct flights between the two countries ( US, Venezuela). Further, while there is a service that delivers renewed  Venezuelan passports, it only applies to passports issued in 2017 or later, while my passport was issued in 2015 . Due to the lack of Consulates, I can't renew nor extend it. Due to the lack of direct flights, I must make a connection in some hemispheric country: Colombia, Panama, seem to be the major local  hubs outside the US . I'm pretty certain I won't have a problem in Caracas itself.
My issue is :Will they let me through at Colombia, Panama, any other country in the Americas, just to make a connecting flight? Last I checked, there are countries that allow the use of expired Venezuelan passports, and Colombia is one of them.  How about at the airline level? Is there a chance there is some private service that could renew my passport? Any chance an embassy would assume the role of providing passport renewals? Any other ideas?
Sorry for my rambling, I'm kind of desperate here.

I ultimately just want to transit somewhere into Caracas.
Thanks.

Comment: You can't go to Mexico for the passport renewal? If you're a US LPR then you don't need a passport to get back to the US

Comment: My status is legal , but won't let me return if I leave. I'm on a petition for TPS. I'm not a resident.

Comment: i wouldn't touch that with a 100-foot pole. You will not be able to reenter even if you ask for previous permission (which will obviously denied, going back to a country you want to get protection from is not a thing you can do)

Comment: Leaving aside the question of you being able to reenter the US, you could try checking Timatic (the system used by airlines) https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&country=/VE  and IATA https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/  to check whether your planned trip looks feasible via a particular route(s). Then call the airline(s) flying that route(s) to confirm their policy.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the embassy of Venezuela in the US at serviciosconsulares@us.embajadavenezuela.org (email from the US DoS), if that fails, maybe contact the embassy in Canada or in Mexico

Comment: I must agree and disagree with @NicolasFormichella. People can definitely travel back to their country of origin while on TPS if they request and are approved for advance parole. Both of my parents did this while on TPS successfully multiple times. Now, where we agree is that advance parole is NOT a guarantee of admission back into the US.

Comment: TPS is granted when (the US government thinks that) people cannot return safely to their home country. If you can go there safely, are you actually eligible?

Comment: @user253751 : I'm running out of money since I can't work. And I found a potential altertnative, but not certain. I have received threats, but I can't live without working forever.

Answer (score 4):

Traveling as a TPS petitioner requires you to [petition the DHS](https://www.uscis.gov/humanitarian/temporary-protected-status) to obtain an Advanced Parole Document (APD), having a valid national passport is not something that will let you skip that requirement (but you'll need a valid one to reenter, see below) :

> If we are still adjudicating your application for TPS, and you wish to travel outside the United States, you must apply for travel authorization. If we approve your request for travel authorization, we will issue you a Form I-512L, Advance Parole Document (APD), to serve as evidence of DHS’s prior consent to your travel outside the United States.

If you don't have such a document, it is very likely that your TPS application will quite surely be denied, and you will be barred from reentry :

> you have a pending TPS application and leave the United States without first obtaining advance parole, we may deny your application for TPS, and you may not be able to reenter the United States.

The page has a warning about the risks of travelling under a TPS :

> We encourage you to read and understand the travel warning on Form I-131 before you request TPS travel authorization or advance parole. You may want to seek legal advice before you request TPS travel authorization or advance parole for travel.

As in TPS petitionner, you are not subject to the absolute ban on returning to the country you get protection from as you are not an Asylee, but I doubt that, without a proper reason to visit, the permission will be approved.

---

To travel, you'd also need a valid passport as (from [I-131 Instructions](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-131instr.pdf))

> An Advance Parole Document is not issued to serve in place of any required passport

Comment: While this answer is very informative, it doesn’t address the OP’s question